# How can Handlebars template render such encoded JSON object data as below?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How can handlebars render such encoded jason object data as below:
{"\u5965\u8fea":1,"\u5b9d\u9a6c":1,"\u5954\u9a70":1};

handlebars：{"\u5965\u8fea":1,"\u5b9d\u9a6c":1,"\u5954\u9a70":1};

Comment: Please add more code to your question. Put in an example where you are trying to fetch and render encoded data as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it isn't possible (in handlebars) to use an unicode-string like \u5965as as key, so you have to use an normal string as key.

```
{
    "abs" : "\u5965"
}
```